# how can i center my text in a css menu?

Tags: css, menu

i have a web site with a javascript menu bar, but the text of the menu is on the left.

```
www.sherlock--holmes.tk
```

How can I center the menu bar text?

```
#header {
    text-aligh: center;
}

/*LAVALAMP START*/

.lavalamp {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-radius : 10px;
    -moz-border-radius : 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px;
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(240,240,240)), to(rgb(204,204,204)));
    background : -moz-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(240,240,240)), to(rgb(204,204,204)));
    height: 18px;
}

.dark {
    background : rgb(89,89,89);
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(107,165,177)), to(rgb(58,196,164)));
    background : -moz-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(89,89,89)), to(rgb(54,54,54)));
    border: 1px solid #272727;
} 

.magenta li a,
.cyan li a,
.yellow li a,
.orange li a,
.dark li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.40);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
    line-height: 20px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 300;
    position: absolute;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.floatr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius : 8px;
    -moz-border-radius : 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius : 8px;
    background : rgba(0,0,0,.20);
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

If I try to play with the options like `<center>`, it doesn't work.

Comment: the site you mentioned has center allined text

Comment: you have this tagged as `javascript` yet there is no javascript code posted, only your css.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to centering the entire menu within the menu bar, I suggest the following adjustments to your CSS:

Push entire UL list right by 50% of container width:

```
ul {
  ...
  left: 50%;
}
```

Push each LI element left by 50% of the UL width:

```
li {
  ...
  left: -50%;
}
```

Prevent horizontal scroll bar caused by UL overflowing on the right:

```
.lavalamp {
  ...
  overflow:hidden;
}
```